# Getting response from Netty server in non-Netty client

Tags: java, netty

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I hope I have adhered to the expected standards.

I have been taking over some code from someone else who isn't working here anymore and I'm pretty much stranded here. I searched and asked some colleagues (not too much Java experience unfortunately) but no-one seems to be able to help me. Searching didn't really help me either.

I'm sending Json requests to a Netty server from a client which intentionally is NOT implemented using Netty. For now it is just a simple Java socket, but the intention is to have a Flask client send requests to the Netty server. The requests arrive (both using Java Sockets and using Python Flask), and get properly processed in the pipeline, but I want to send a response to the client and although I suspect where in the code to send the response I'm clearly missing out on something as I don't get any response. Any suggestions?

**The Java Socket client** (note that the json1 and json2 strings have been omitted from the snippet here as they are rather long, but they are formatted properly). Posting requests using a Socket and the related output stream. The response part (with the input stream for the same socket) is just some test which I have my doubt about, but not sure how to do this otherwise (and that's why I kept it here). I've been seeing plenty of examples with clients implementing Netty interfaces and that seems to work fine, but as said I want a client not using Netty to be able to receive the responses as well (if that's possible at all).

```
String serverResponse;

for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 12000);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.write(json1 + i + json2);
            out.flush();

            // Testing only - trying to get the response back from the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            while(true) {
                if ((serverResponse = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.info("server says", serverResponse);
                    break;
                }
            }

            out.close();
            s.close();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

**MCTcpServer.java**

```
/**
 * Abstract TCP Server class. this class should be implemented in the subclass to implement an actual server.
 *
 * @param <R> The data to be read from the socket.
 * @param <W> data to be written (in case of duplex) from the socket.
 */

public abstract class MFTcpServer<R, W> {

    protected final AtomicBoolean started;

    protected MFTcpServer() {
        this.started = new AtomicBoolean();
    }

    /**
     * Start the server.
     *
     * @param initializer the channel initializers. they will be called when a new client connects to the server.
     * @return instance of tcp server
     */
    public final MFTcpServer<R, W> start(ChannelInitializer<Channel> initializer) {
        if (!started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server already started");
        }

        doStart(initializer);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Start the server and wait for all the threads to be finished before shutdown.
     * @param initializer the channel initializers. they will be called when a new client connects to the server.
     */
    public final void startAndAwait(ChannelInitializer<Channel> initializer) {
        start(initializer);
        awaitShutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Shutdown the server
     * @return true if successfully shutdown.
     */
    public final boolean shutdown() {
        return !started.compareAndSet(true, false) || doShutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Wait for all the threads to be finished before shutdown.
     */
    public abstract void awaitShutdown();

    /**
     * Do the shutdown now.
     * @return true if successfully shutdown
     */
    public abstract boolean doShutdown();

    /**
     * start the server
     * @param initializer the channel initializers. they will be called when a new client connetcs to the server.
     * @return instance of tcp server
     */
    public abstract MFTcpServer<R, W> doStart(ChannelInitializer<Channel> initializer);

    /**
     *
     * @return the port where the server is running.
     */
    public abstract int getPort();
```

**MFNetty4TcpServer.java** Actual server implementation

```
public class MFNetty4TcpServer<R, W> extends MFTcpServer<R, W> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MFNetty4TcpServer.class);
    private static final int BOSS_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 2;

    private int port;
    private ServerBootstrap bootstrap;
    private ChannelFuture bindFuture;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     *
     * @param port port where to listen
     */
    protected MFNetty4TcpServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        final NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(0, new DefaultEventExecutorGroup
                (BOSS_THREAD_POOL_SIZE));
        final NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(0, new DefaultEventExecutorGroup
                (JsonProducerConfig.THREAD_POOL_SIZE));

        bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public MFNetty4TcpServer<R, W> doStart(ChannelInitializer<Channel> initializer) {
        bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

            @Override
            protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {

                if (initializer != null) {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(initializer);
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            bindFuture = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
            if (!bindFuture.isSuccess()) {
                // Connection not successful
                throw new RuntimeException(bindFuture.cause());
            }
            SocketAddress localAddress = bindFuture.channel().localAddress();
            if (localAddress instanceof InetSocketAddress) {
                port = ((InetSocketAddress) localAddress).getPort();
                logger.info("Started server at port: " + port);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Error waiting for binding server port: " + port, e);
        }

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void awaitShutdown() {
        try {
            bindFuture.channel().closeFuture().await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.interrupted(); // Reset the interrupted status
            logger.error("Interrupted while waiting for the server socket to close.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doShutdown() {
        try {
            bindFuture.channel().close().sync();
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to shutdown the server.", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a tcp server at the defined port.
     *
     * @param port port to listen to
     * @param <R>  data to be read
     * @param <W>  data to be written back. Only in case of duplex connection.
     * @return instance of tcp server.
     */
    public static <R, W> MFTcpServer<R, W> create(int port) {
        return new MFNetty4TcpServer<>(port);
    }

}
```

**JsonProducerConfig.java** The pipeline is setup here.

```
/**
 * Spring Configuration class of the application.
 */
@Configuration
@Import({DatabusConfig.class})
public class JsonProducerConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonProducerConfig.class);

    public static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;

    public static final String TCP_SERVER = "tcpServer";
    public static final String CHANNEL_PIPELINE_INITIALIZER = "channel_initializer";
    public static final String MF_KAFKA_PRODUCER = "mf_kafka_producer";
    public static final String JSON_AVRO_CONVERTOR = "jsonAvroConvertor";

    @Value("#{systemProperties['tcpserver.port']?:'12000'}")
    private String tcpServerPort;

    @Bean(name = TCP_SERVER)
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public MFTcpServer nettyTCPServer() {
        return MFNetty4TcpServer.create(Integer.parseInt(tcpServerPort));
    }

    @Bean(name = MF_KAFKA_PRODUCER)
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public MFKafkaProducer pushToKafka() {
        return new MFKafkaProducer();
    }

    @Bean(name = JSON_AVRO_CONVERTOR)
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public JsonAvroConvertor jsonAvroConvertor() {
        return new JsonAvroConvertor();
    }

    /**
     * This is where the pipeline is set for processing of events.
     *
     * @param jsonAvroConvertor converts json to avro
     * @param kafkaProducer     pushes to kafka
     * @return chanenl initializers pipeline.
     */
    @Bean(name = CHANNEL_PIPELINE_INITIALIZER)
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ChannelInitializer<Channel> channelInitializers(JsonAvroConvertor jsonAvroConvertor,
                                                           MFKafkaProducer kafkaProducer) {
        return new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {

                if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                    log.info("initChannel - initing channel...");

                channel.pipeline().addLast(new NioEventLoopGroup(0, new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(THREAD_POOL_SIZE)));
                channel.pipeline().addLast(new JsonObjectDecoder(1048576));
                channel.pipeline().addLast(jsonAvroConvertor);
                channel.pipeline().addLast(kafkaProducer);

                if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                    log.info("channel = " + channel.toString());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**JsonProducer.java** The main program

```
public class JsonProducer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonProducer.class);

    private static MFTcpServer tcpServer;

    /**
     * Main startup method
     *
     * @param args not used
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("solschema", "false");

        try {

            // the shutdown hook.
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(
                    () -> {
                        if (tcpServer != null) {
                            tcpServer.shutdown();
                        }
                    }
            ));

            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new
                    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JsonProducerConfig.class);

            tcpServer = (MFTcpServer) context.getBean(JsonProducerConfig.TCP_SERVER);

            ChannelInitializer<Channel> channelInitializer = (ChannelInitializer<Channel>) context.
                    getBean(JsonProducerConfig.CHANNEL_PIPELINE_INITIALIZER);

            tcpServer.startAndAwait(channelInitializer);

        } catch (Exception t) {
            log.error("Error while starting JsonProducer ", t);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

The **MFKafkaProducer.java** as the last channel in the pipeline. Note the ctx.writeAndFlush(msg) in the channelRead method which is where I understand the response should be initiated. But what after that. When running this channelFuture.isSuccess() evaluates to false. The response object was an attempt to a String response.

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class MFKafkaProducer extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MFKafkaProducer.class);

    @Resource
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Resource(name = DatabusConfig.ADMIN)
    Admin admin;

    private Map<String, IProducer> streams = new HashMap<>();

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() {
        removeAllStreams(); // then stop writing to producers
    }

    /**
     * @param clickRecord the record to be pushed to kafka
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void handle(GenericRecord clickRecord) throws Exception {
        Utf8 clientId = null;
        try {
            clientId = (Utf8) clickRecord.get(SchemaUtil.APP_ID);
            stream(producer(clientId.toString()), clickRecord);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String message = "Could not push click data for clientId:" + clientId;
            log.warn("handle - " + message + "!!!", e);
            assert clientId != null;
            removeStream(clientId.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * removes all the streams
     */
    private void removeAllStreams() {
        Set<String> strings = streams.keySet();

        for (String clientId : strings) {
            removeStream(clientId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * removes a particular stream
     *
     * @param clientId the stream to be removed
     */
    private void removeStream(String clientId) {
        Assert.notEmpty(streams);
        IProducer producer = streams.get(clientId);
        producer.stopProducer();
        streams.remove(clientId);
    }

    /**
     * @param producer    the producer where data needs to be written
     * @param clickRecord teh record to be written
     */
    private void stream(IProducer producer, GenericRecord clickRecord) {
        producer.send(clickRecord);
    }

    /**
     * This will create a producer in case it is not already created.
     * If already created return the already present one
     *
     * @param clientId stream id
     * @return the producer instance
     */
    private IProducer producer(String clientId) {
        if (streams.containsKey(clientId)) {
            return streams.get(clientId);
        } else {
            IProducer producer = admin.createKeyTopicProducer(SchemaUtil.APP_ID, "test_" + clientId, new ICallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(long offset) {
                    if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                        log.info("onSuccess - Data at offset:" + offset + " send.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(long offset, Exception ex) {
                    if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                        log.info("onError - Data at offset:" + offset + " failed. Exception: ", ex);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStreamClosed() {
                    log.warn("onStreamClosed - Stream:" + clientId + " closed.");
                    removeStream(clientId);
                }
            });
            producer.startProducer();
            streams.put(clientId, producer);
            return producer;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        log.debug("KafkaProducer - channelRead() called with " + "ctx = [" + ctx + "], msg = [" + msg + "]");

        if (msg instanceof GenericRecord) {
            GenericRecord genericRecord = (GenericRecord) msg;
            try {
                handle(genericRecord);
                log.debug("channelRead sending response");
                Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
                ByteBuf response = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Just a response", charset);
                ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
                future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
                        if (channelFuture.isSuccess())
                            log.info("channelRead - future.operationComplete - Response has been delivered to all channels");
                        else
                            log.info("channelRead - future.operationComplete - Response has NOT been delivered to all channels");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Something went wrong processing the generic record: " + msg + "\n ", ex);
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("KafkaProducer - msg not of Type Generic Record !!! " + msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        log.error("Something went wrong writing to Kafka: \n", cause);
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend to log ChannelFuture#cause() if ChannelFuture#isSuccess() returns false

Comment: what happens if you actually write your `ByteBuf response` back to the channel instead of the received `msg`?

Comment: Thanks @forty-two, this was indeed an issue as the message being serialized was not a ByteBuf but a GenericRecord. I solved this by creating a ByteBuf from the genericRecord (just for testing purposes now to see if there is any response at all:                `ByteBuf response = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(genericRecord.toString(), charset);
                ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(response);`  @Moh-Aw: I do get successful delivery of the message now from the ChannelFuture, but somehow I don't see it arriving at my client yet (it is a very simplistic client which might be a cause).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally solved it. It was indeed a poor implementation of the client. By using a SocketChannel instead of just a Socket I do see the replies on my client side as well.

Comment: I suggest that you write your solution and accept it to close this issue and so others can take advantage of it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ChannelFuture#cause() I noticed I was not serializing a ByteBuf object, but a GenericRecord instead. Using

```
ByteBuf response = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(genericRecord.toString(), charset); 
ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
```

the GenericRecord gets converted to a ButeBuf and sends a response using the writeAndFlush method.

The test client using a Socket implementation somehow never really received a response, but by using a SocketChannel this was resolved as well.